# Push notifications with urban airship on distribution

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have released two apps to the Apple store for distribution. They are exactly the same except one is free and one is paid. The free version is supported by ads.

Nothing is different in the code besides the ad and I have created the certificates and distribution profiles in exactly the same way.

On Urban Airship we created two apps. One for free, one for paid.

We bundled the certificates correctly as far as we know and uploaded each one to Urban Airship.

In production, only the Free version is sending out push notifications while the paid version is not.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the cause? We're at complete loss here so anything will be helpful.

Comment: Please double check your airshipconfig file which contains the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be problem/solution
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60710-can-t-get-a-device-token-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-seen-in-console